# RandomForest Classifier object in arguments

Tags: python, random, arguments, classification

I'm currently working on a random forest classifier, using gridsearch to get the best parameters

So when I get my parameters they are in my var :

```
params = {'bootstrap': 'True', 
          'criterion': 'entropy', 
          'max_depth': 'None', 
          'max_features': '3', 
          'min_samples_leaf': '4', 
          'min_samples_split': '3'}
```

And I would like to do something like that :

`clf = RandomForestClassifier(params)`

But here `params` take the place of `n_estimators` so I have some errors like :

```
ValueError: n_estimators must be an integer, got <class 'dict'>.
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to unpack the parameters for the function call with

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(**params)
```

Let me show you the result of various ways using a dict as function argument for a function with default arguments. The comment after the function call is the result of the print.

```
def foo(bar=None, baz=None):
    print(bar, baz)

params = { "bar": "Hello", "baz": "World"}

# pass params as the first parameter
foo(params) # {'baz': 'World', 'bar': 'Hello'} None

# pass keys of params as parameters (order is out of our hands)
foo(*params) # baz bar

# unpacks params with key=value as parameters
foo(**params) # Hello World
```

I noticed that you're always using a string representation in your values, even for `None` or `True` - you might run into trouble if the function expects actually `None` or a boolean instead of a string. Better check the API what values are valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yep I know that I'll be in trouble with the types, I'm looking for an equivalent of the `var = int(a) | bool(a) | a` but it doesn't works x)

Comment: Did the trick with a regex ! :)
`'(?P<key>[a-z_]+)=((?P<int>\d+)|(?P<bool>True|False)|(?P<none>None)|(?P<string>[a-zA-Z]+))'`
and after some if/elif ^^